# Can't seem to set explicit WAN source IP for pfSense port-forward rule

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, pfsense

I have setup a firewall port-forwarding rule that allows me to RDP into my home machine from work. However, I want to allow RDP traffic (so TCP port 3389) *only* from my work IP since it's static (and to prevent brute-force attacks from the internet). However, for some reason I cannot change the "source address" field in the firewall rule. It is set to 'any' currently, but when I try and change it, there is a circle with a line thru it (a "no" symbol) over the cursor.

Worth noting that this is a Firewall > NAT rule, so I also tried to edit it there (under Firewall / NAT / Port Forward). However, this does not work either and displays the same "no" symbol over the cursor. I can change the source to "WAN address" but **I cannot actually *set* the WAN address**. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Firewall > NAT > Port Forward > Edit (show advanced) > Source: **Single Host or Alias** < this was the part that I was missing. I was trying to use "WAN Address."

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a 1:1 NAT rule i think

It is in Firewall --> NAT --> 1:1

Here you can specify which external IP is allowed to go into the internal IP

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/1:1_NAT